# Simple force vector question (where does the missing force come from)?

Tags: forces

A painting weighing 1 kg is suspended by two wires (so as to form a triangle).

[image]

The angle between each wire and the painting is 45 degrees.

The question asks: What is the force on one wire?

After a bit of trig the answer turns out to be 6.94 N per wire.

However, this means the total force on both wires will be 13.88 N.

But surely the total force can only be 9.81 N since the painting only weighs 1 kg.

That means a force of 4.07 N has come out of nowhere.

Have I made a mistake somewhere?

If not, where does this extra force originate from?

How can there be more force in the system than what gravity gives it?

Sorry if this question is over-simple, but it's got me stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force on the wire is also along the wire. So, if its horizontal component and vertical components are analysed, we would see that the net horizontal components is 0 while the net vertical component balances the weight of the picture. Try out the calculation and you would see it for yourself.

Comment: Thanks. So the two opposing forces in the two wires cancel out to zero? I can accept that.But still, I can't see what causes those two forces in the first place. A force must be caused by some kind of energy, right? But all the energy from gravity is going into causing the downward force of 9.81 N.

Comment: There is no need for any type of energy to cause a force. Gravity uses no energy to pull the painting down. There is definitely no law about conservation of forces. Especially if you go on to take engineering, you'll find that causing extremely large forces with small inputs is common.

Comment: You should see that the horizontal and vertical component to which you resolved your force depends on the coordinate system which you chose. That is there are infinite perpendicular component pairs to which our force can be resolved to. We are just representing our force as a sum of two perpendicular forces in a perticular refference frame to help us in the calculation.